# Javascript loop for fetching wikipedia data not terminating

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, wikipedia

I have been working on a pretty big javascript function, and when I finally thought it was done, it stopped working completely.

Here it is:

```
function getLinksFrom(title) {
  var returnArray = [],
      plcontinue = '',
      url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=links&titles=' + title + '&format=json&pllimit=500&plnamespace=0&callback=?';
  while (returnArray.length === 0 || plcontinue !== '') {
      if (plcontinue !== '') {
          url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=links&titles=' + title + '&format=json&pllimit=500&plnamespace=0&plcontinue=' + plcontinue + '&callback=?';
      }
      $.ajax({url: url, 
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
              for (key in data['query']['pages']) {
                  links = data['query']['pages'][key]['links'];
              }
              for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i += 1) {
                  returnArray.push(links[i]['title']);
              }
              if (data.hasOwnProperty('query-continue')) {
                  plcontinue = data['query-continue']['links']['plcontinue'];
              } else {
                  plcontinue = '';
              }
          }
      });
  }
  return returnArray;
}
```

from what I can tell, it must be getting stuck in the while loop, as the page just freezes up. But with each loop, returnArray grows, and I'm testing it with something that won't set plcontinue to anything.

Any idea what is going wrong? Possibly something with asynchronous loading, I'm new at that.

EDIT: So I've figured out via helpful comments that it's looping again and again making more and more requests without waiting for the ajax to finish before starting again. How can I stop it from doing that?

Comment: Is data printing to the console?

Comment: This will run an extremely tight `while` loop that will execute many ajax requests.  A better (thought not necessarily ideal) version of what you're trying to achieve can be done by removing `while` and making the ajax call synchronous.

Comment: What your asking for is arguably against Wikipedia's Terms of Use. Has your script "been approved by the Wikipedia community"? http://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Terms_of_Use#4._Refraining_from_Certain_Activities

Comment: Try to debug your code and see where it is going and also check your console as you are printing the data in the console

Comment: asifrc No, the data is not printing to the console.


Jeff, I just realized now that it might be sending a zillion requests. I only want it to send one at a time, which was in agreement with the terms last time I checked.

Comment: Before the $.ajax() function, place `console.log('calling ajax');` and then comment out the whole $.ajax({}) block and try `$.get(url,{},function(data) { console.log(data); });` and let us know if it returns anything..

Comment: asifrc Oh jeez, it logs 'calling ajax' thousands of times.

Comment: Additionally, if you're using chrome (I'm sure you can do the same in other browsers), going to the Network tab of the console will display all the responses from ajax requests..

Comment: Does your console tell you if you're getting responses from your ajax requests? (and are you using chrome by chance?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is that AJAX is *asynchronous*. That means that when JS needs to perform request, it sends it and goes on, continuing to execute the rest of the code. When request is done, callback is fired.

So in your code it would works like that:

1. Initialization of variables
2. While loop condition check. Condition is true, so go to the loop body.
3. Executing ajax request. We send request and go on.
4. Again check condition. Since nothing changed (request haven't any time to complete), condition is still true.
5. And so on.

Eventually, maybe, one of dozen of request will end, modify `returnArray` and `plcontinue`, but this could take long time because what you have in your function body is, basically, infinite (almost) loop, which takes most of CPU resources.

The solution is to replace iteration with recursion: instead of iterating in infinite loop untill success, you can recurse until success. Delete while loop from `getLinksFrom` and add `getLinksFrom()` to the ajax request callback.

Another approack is to do that request *synchronous*. There is a special flag for it.

Comment: Barmaley.exe thanks for the awesome answer! I've run into a new problem that I asked about here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722193/setting-variable-to-result-of-function-acting-very-strange/14722234